# Adding Security Extensions such as a Firewall (Other than the one's provided by Microsoft) to Azure SQL Data warehosue

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Is it possible?
[Secure DB in SQL DW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-overview-manage-security)

Can I add a custom firewall extension and disable the one provided my MS?

Comment: you are using database as service,so you will not be able to do it

Comment: you can  set IP restriction on your Azure DB using sp_set_firewall_rule.
check out this article:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270017.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, PaaS services don't allow such levels of customization. You can add custom firewall rules within the portal or through T-SQL as sqlandmore.com suggests. Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn270017.aspx for changing with T-SQL and here for portal changes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings